# CA0055 on System.Web.MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I've just migrated my ASP.NET MVC 3 application from windows 7 /VS2010 to Windows 8 / Visual Studio 2012. I'm getting a weird Code Analysis error.

> CA0055    Error Running Code Analysis CA0055 : Could not load MyAssembly.dll. The following error was encountered while reading module 'System.Web.Mvc': Could not resolve type reference: [System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]System.Web.Razor.Parser.SyntaxTree.CodeSpan.  [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)

Adding a reference to System.Web.Razor did not help. Work-around for now is to disable code analysis for the web project. Does anyone know why this error occurs and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that MyAssembly.dll references another System.Web.Razor version compared with the one you have in your project.

Can also be different .Net frameworks in different projects.

Comment: Yeah i guess you're right. After a good night of sleep I migrated the project to MVC 4 using this manual guide:
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Work's like a charm now. Thanks!